# Can Only Extend to External Monitor

Tags: lenovo-laptop, external-display, laptop-display, hdtv

I am trying to figure out how to make my external monitor the default display. I am able to connect the laptop with VGA to the monitor and extend display. But when I try to show desktop only on monitor 2, I get a message 'Mode Not Supported' on the monitor.

I am using Windows 7 x64 on a Lenovo N500 with a Vizio 22" HDTV.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured out the problem. I had to output to monitor on Intel Graphics Media Accelerator.